# How to find out all the capital words in a corpus in R

Tags: r, text-mining

So, I have a document corpus and i need to find all the words which are all capital(i.e., every character in that word is capital) in all the documents in R. I am not sure how to find that. I have looked at the text mining 'tm' package in R and there is no such functions which can find that.

Input String: `"Russia Is THE BiggEST cOUNTRY"`

Output required: `"THE"`

How to do this using "tm" package?

Answer (score 2):

You can use gregexpr and regmatches:

```
unlist(regmatches(abc, gregexpr('\\b[A-Z]+\\b', abc)))
[1] "THE"
```

## data

```
abc <- "Russia Is THE BiggEST cOUNTRY"
```

Answer (score 2):

With stringr (if you want to find all such words (as a vector) with caps not just the first one):

```
s = "Russia Is THE BiggEST cOUNTRY IN the WORLD"
library(stringr)
unlist(str_match_all(s, "\\b[A-Z]+\\b"))
[1] "THE"   "IN"    "WORLD"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use regular expression.

```
sub('.*(\\b[A-Z]+\\b).*','\\1',string)
#[1] "THE"
```

Comment: this will only find one word, try for example with `string <- "Russia IS THE BiggEST cOUNTRY"`